# I get an error message "expected an identifier" and i do not know how to get rid of it in C program

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error

in the line

```
struct con* = (struct phone_book*)malloc(size * sizeof(struct phone_book*));
```

i get an error on `=` and the error says expected an identifier.

what do i do?

thank you

Comment: why is that not `struct phone_book* = (struct phone_book*)` ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and post an [mcve]. I suspect that you need a variable name following `con*`. You don't need to cast the return from malloc.

Answer (score 2):

The `struct` keyword is expected to be followed by a struct name.  It appears you tried to create a variable with type `struct cont` but with no variable name after.

Based on the call to `malloc` and the cast, you probably want this variable to have type `struct phone_book *`:

```
struct phone_book *con = malloc(size * sizeof(struct phone_book*));
```

Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc` as that can mask a missing include in your code.